# The first command run in the terminal is extremely slow

Tags: command-line, 16.04

I ran into a strange problem whereby the first command I issue in the terminal is extremely slow to execute. For example, I might begin a compilation and it would take eternity. But, if I stop it with Ctrl+C and then run the same command again, it's fast. What could cause this problem and how do I solve it?

To be more specific, I think it happens with CPU-intensive commands. For example, when I run `g++` to compile `C++` code or when I begin `emacs` and it loads all kinds of modes. When this happens and I look at the output of `htop`, it shows that the command in question uses 3-4% of CPU instead of 99-100% as it would normally do.

Comment: could you give an example of such a command, please? Does it happen with any command?

Comment: @Zanna I added an example.

Comment: @Zanna So, why would this become the case? It used not to be so. Also, the amount of data read from the disk is very small. In the case of `g++`, we are taking (with all the standard library headers included) about 200K lines of code, i.e. several MB...

Comment: My guess is that the first run is "normal speed", throttled by the slow disk access needed to fetch all necessary data. When you run the same thing again then, much of the disk data is still in Ubuntu's disk cache in RAM, which is of course a whole lot faster to access than the real HDD. Now that the slow disk I/O is eliminated, the CPU usage of course goes much higher because it doesn't have to wait for disk data.

Comment: Can you run that slow command once in a fresh session, run it again to see if it's still faster the second time, then run `sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to drop Ubuntu's disk cache and then run the same command again to see if it's still faster or slow again?

Comment: @ByteCommander I could not reproduce the issue with compilation this time. Emacs did take forever (using 0% CPU). When I started it a second time, it started instantly and did so every time after that, even after clearing the cache as suggested.

Comment: Interesting. Then I unfortunately have no idea what might be going on.

Comment: did you find the cause or get rid of the problem?

Comment: @Zanna No, I did not.